# Pass values from view to controller model on httppost from ajaxcall not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, http-post

I have the requirement to insert text entered in the textareafor when the text is changed in the textbox.I used jquery change function to get this done.I get the controller hit on the actionmethod from ajax but, text from view is not getting passed to model.
(**Code used: MVC4 /entity dbfirst/ razor**)
***Here is my detailed code.***

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Dailynotes()
{            
    return View();
}

//I’m getting this code hit from ajaxcall, but dashboard model is null????????
tblDailyNotes note = new tblDailyNotes();
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Dailynotes(DashboardViewModel model)
{
    int noteid = 0;
    model.Dailynotes = note.Note;
    _scheduler.InsertDailynote(note);//this is the sp to insert the note
    return View();                 
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<div id="content">

    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                  .Name("tabstrip")
                  .Items(tabstrip =>
                   {
                      tabstrip.Add().Text("Daily Notes")
                      .Selected(true)
                      .LoadContentFrom("Dailynotes", "Scheduler");

                   })
               )
</div>
<div>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Dailynotes", "Scheduler");}
</div>
```

**Dailynotes.cshtml:**

```
@model  proj.Models.DashboardViewModel

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Dailynotes, new {@class="k-textbox",id="dailynotes"})

<script>
    $("#dailynotes").change(function () {
        alert("Changed");


        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            cache: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: window.location.pathname + "Scheduler/Dailynotes",
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            },
            complete: function () { }

         });

    });
```

**Dashboardviewmodel.cs**

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
    public string Dailynotes { get; set; }
    public string Weeklynotes { get; set; }

}
```

I get the ajax calling the post action, but dashboardmodel does not return the text I entered in the textbox in the model.

Please help..

Edit 1: 
/not working

```
 $("#dailynotes").change(function () {
        alert("Changed");
        var dailynotes = $('#dailynotes').val();

        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.pathname + 'Scheduler/Dailynotes',
            type: 'POST',
            //data: $('form').serialize(),
            data:{  model:dailynotes   }
        })
         .success(function (result) {
             alert("note saved successfully");

         });
    });
```

Comment: try changing the url like this : `url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "AreaName" })",`

Comment: try changing the type : `POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the model on view to the controller using ajax call you can use

```
data: $('form').serialize()
```

if you want to pass only text then only one parameter with type string needed to be passed to and not whole model.

for second option you can use

```
var dailynotes=$('#dailynotes').val();
```

and in ajax call

```
data:{DailyNotes:dailynotes};
```

and controller action with accept argument of type string which will be `DailyNotes`

Comment: My dailynotesview contains only one textbox.I created a controller to get the values from textbox in httppost, here model receives null.

Comment: check the udpated question, now the controller is not getting hit

Comment: have u passed the string parameter and is that alert shown and if its httppost why you have written get in ajax

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the data param of ajax function, where you want to post your values

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Sample:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: In my condition I pass only the text, so what can be value for data? Please help

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
$("#dailynotes").change(function () {
    alert("Changed");
    var dailynotes = $('#dailynotes').val();

    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname + '/Scheduler/Dailynotes',
        type: 'POST',
        //data: $('form').serialize(),
        data:{  model:dailynotes   }
    })
     .success(function (result) {
         alert("note saved successfully");

    });
});
```

notice that I've changed the line `data:{  model:dailynotes   }`. This is because the controller action expects a parameter called `model`

i.e.  `public ActionResult Dailynotes(DashboardViewModel model)`

I also changed the type to `POST` as the action is marked with this attribute.

Comment: This is giving me null value for model in POST Action Method.

Comment: No, the actionmethod is not getting hit

Comment: hmm - sorry, based on what i had understood to be the case, this should have passed the value. that said, i can't see where `#dailynotes` id gets set anywhere?? i.e. all i see is`tabstrip.Add().Text("Daily Notes")` - no id associated

Comment: .Text("Dailynotes") is the tabname
 .LoadContentFrom("Dailynotes", "Scheduler"); // this line loads the textbox for the tab.

Comment: @gs11111 : It's working fine at my end after making the modification told in the comment section of your query.

Comment: even now the model is null,